# moment.js will not parse UK format date even when setting the locale

Tags: momentjs

Quite simply, this is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/NibblyPig/k9zb4ysp/

```
moment.locale('en-GB');

var d = moment('22/12/2019');

alert(d);
```

I would expect this to parse, however it says invalid date.

I have referenced `moment.js` and the `locale/en-gb.js`

I'm writing a global control so the date may come in in a variety of formats.

If I put in a variety of American dates they all work, for example `12/12/2019`, `12/12/2019 23:04` etc.

However the locale command does not appear to do anything and I cannot get a single date to parse. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the format as the second argument for `moment()`, as discussed [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

```
moment.locale('en-GB');

var d = moment('22/12/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY');

alert(d);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a4gu6kfz/

From the docs:

> If you know the format of an input string, you can use that to parse a
>   moment.
>
> moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");

Comment: What if I don't know the format? It might have a time component, or a 2 day year, or a 1 character day, etc all of which works in american format

Comment: I wish I had an answer for that...parsing unknown date formats seems like an impossible problem to be solved easily. Can't the dates come in timestamps?

Comment: I've worked around it by doing string manipulation to split it and switch the day/month around, with some code to add padded 0 and a wraparound check for 2 digit years. Parsing the time is another matter altogether, I've just replaced : and , with empty string and tacked it on the end (I'm using it to do sorting) so it'll do. If a better solution presents itself I'll switch it out.

Comment: The only thing I see with string manipulation is it's not that flexible considering there are formats which you are not aware of. Sooner or later you will hit a corner case. But your solution sounds quite clever indeed.

Comment: Mind posting it as an answer? I'll happily upvote it.

Comment: It's a bit tacky but sure

Comment: @NibblyPig Playing with the original fiddle, a format of `DD/MM/YYYY` seems to accept (and correctly process) most variants: `22/12/2019`, `22-12-2019`, `22.12.2019`, `22.12.19` and `22.2.19` (the last showing it handles non-zero-filled numbers). As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47729257/2096401) to a similar question, you can also pass the locale as a third parameter, though that doesn't seem to be needed in the cases I tried.

Comment: The original fiddle gives 'invalid date' when I run it with no changes, are you not experiencing that?

Comment: FTR, I also get `invalid date`

Comment: @NibblyPig Sorry, I meant when I added the format string as a second parameter. Using `var d = moment('22/12/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY');` seemed to work for 1 or 2 digit days/months; 2 or 4 digit years and several separators (`/`, `-` and `.`).

Comment: and must `import 'moment/locale/en-gb'`

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is no need to write your own complex logic to parse your input, you can use [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) (or [`moment(String, String[], String, Boolean)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/)), as suggested by [Thales Minussi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57111623/4131048).

[`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) is the good choice only if your input is in ISO 8601 or RFC 2822 compliant form.

In your case, you can probably use *Localized formats* listed [in the format section of the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). If you have a list of possible formats, I think that the best choice is tho use [`moment(String, String[])`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/).

Please note that, by default: *Moment's parser is very forgiving*, so using default [Forgiving Mode](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/forgiving-mode/) will handle *"any"* character as separator.

Here a live sample:

```js
moment.locale('en-GB');

['22/12/2019', '22/12/2019 15:00',
 '22-12-2019', '22-12-2019 15:00',
 '1-3-2019', '1-12-2019', '22-1-2019'
].forEach((elem) => {
  var d = moment(elem, 'L LT');
  console.log(d.format());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/en-gb.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Still hoping there's a nice moment js way to do this but in the meantime I just bashed this together. Pretty nasty and it will probably go wrong in 80 years or so.

http://jsfiddle.net/NibblyPig/k9zb4ysp/22/

```
var a = "23/03/19 12:42:21.123";

var datePart = a.substring(0, a.indexOf(" "));
var timePart = a.substring(a.indexOf(" ") + 1);

var dateParts = datePart.split("/");

if (dateParts[0].length == 1) dateParts[0] = "0" + dateParts[0];
if (dateParts[1].length == 1) dateParts[1] = "0" + dateParts[1];
if (dateParts[2].length == 2) {

    var threshold = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear().toString().substring(2)) +  10;

if (parseFloat(dateParts[2]) > threshold ) {
    dateParts[2] = "19" + dateParts[2];
  }
  else
  {
        dateParts[2] = "20" + dateParts[2];
  }
}

alert (parseFloat(dateParts[2] + dateParts[1] + dateParts[0] + timePart.replace(/:/g, "").replace(/\./g, "")));
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't solve every usecase, but in your specific example if you want just a simple date (with no time component) auto-parsed in UK format you can just use the `'L'` format string having set the locale to `'en-GB'`

Your example with this change ([your jsfiddle also](https://jsfiddle.net/ncq0xbsp/))

```
moment.locale('en-GB');

// just pass 'L' i.e. local date format as a parsing format here
var d = moment('22/12/2019', 'L'); 

alert(d);
```

It's quite nice because you get the auto parsing of various formats you wanted for free. For instance this works just the same:

```
var d = moment('22-12-2019', 'L');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a date using moment.js in a desired format -

```
return moment(aDateVar).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```