# How to change moment locale for one parced value

Tags: momentjs

I have a global 'ru' setting for moment, but i need to parce 'en' date in one of the functions. How can i do it?

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-cloud-de49h?file=/src/App.js).

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import "moment/locale/ru";

// global
moment.locale("ru");

const parceEngDate = () => {
  return moment("Nov 04, 2019", "MMM D YYYY").locale("en").toDate().toString();
};

export default function App() {
  // Fri Jan 04 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300
  // It's november, not january!
  return <div className="App">{parceEngDate()}</div>;
}
```

Comment: See [Parse date with moment.js with locales](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47728828/4131048), you can use [`moment(String, String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), so in your case `moment("Nov 04, 2019", "MMM D YYYY", "en")`

Comment: @VincenzoC thanks, please answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`moment(String, String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), so in your case `moment("Nov 04, 2019", "MMM D YYYY", "en")`.

Snippet:

```js
console.log( moment("Nov 04, 2019", "MMM D YYYY", "en").toDate().toString() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```