# What would be the proper way of parsing strings to Dates?

Tags: typescript, string, date, datetime, parsing

So I am making a web crawling api, which crawls the date from a website too. But parsing the html always ends up in a string. So I would need to parse that string to date.

Also, I'm talking about hungarian dates like: "2022. október 22. 12:00" or "2022.11.01. 16:30".

I'm using nestjs and typeScript and I have already tried every date.parse function, but I got NaN or Invalid Date.
Can somebody help me parsing theese please?

Comment: Did you look at https://date-fns.org/v2.24.0/docs/parse ? It has `locale` option for such cases

Comment: Have you tried [`momentjs`](https://momentjs.com/)?  
You also might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728828/parse-date-with-moment-js-with-locales) useful.

Comment: dayjs works for 2022.11.01. 16:30, but doesn't work for the first date even with the hungarian locale :(

https://replit.com/@TJHiggins1/Stack-Overflow-Parse-date#index.ts

Comment: Yes, same here :(